# Using @Enumerated and @Formula with Case on a Field in Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a simple Class Entity, in which i want to automatically change the status of the Class to Expired, if the present date is more than the scheduledClassDateTime.

My Class Status is a Enum with types OnGoing and Expired.

I am trying to use the below to change the status to Expired.

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Formula(value = "case when class_Date_Time<now()) then 'EXPIRED' end ")
private ClassStatus classStatus = ClassStatus.OnGoing;
```

I am getting the below error (NOTE: this is now resolved, but saved below for reference of others)

> FUNCTION classDateTime.compareTo does not exist
>
> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

**UPDATE**

1. The issue has been resolved with the help of @stainslav original hint and was because of the Object queries being used instead of Native query. I changed the code in the question to reflect this.
2. The problem now is that @Formula is not saving EXPIRED to the database...it is coming up as blank. I am not sure I am using @Formula right

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL is wrong

```
case when classDateTime.compareTo(LocalDateTime.now())<0 then 'EXPIRED' [else 'VALID'] end
```

where else part is optional. Original SQL miss `end`

Comment: +1 Oops...that was a typo. I corrected it and I get the following error - "FUNCTION classDateTime.compareTo does not exist". Edited the question appropriately and upvoted for your effort.

Comment: now it seems you are trying to use java class in SQL expression. DB does not know about your classes. Use DB table column instead as well as DB specific expression instead of `now()`

Comment: That was it. I was using JPQL queries instead of native query. However, I am strangely facing a issue where the EXPIRED is not being saved to database. Is my understanding of @Formula incorrect ?

Comment: `@Formula` is a read only expression marker. It could have an expression or even subselect e.g. `@Formula(value = "(select count(*) from ... where some_id=id) ")`. It cannot be saved.

Comment: My bad. Is there an alternative JPA annotation that functions like @Formula but saves to Database ? If not how could this saving to database be done

Comment: I would introduce two fields - readonly one based on the `@Formula` and a status field associated with real column to let it be saved. Also use `@PrePersist` or `@PreUpdate` to check the status value and update the status from the read only formula based field.

Comment: Perfect guidance. I am also considering using a cron job or a Database Trigger, since my use case is slightly more complicated. I would upvote this answer chain twice if i could :)

Answer (score 1):

You must use native SQL inside @Formula, so something like:

```
classDateTime > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: Thx. you spotted it right, but Stainislav had suggested this earlier. +1